# Ionic iOS app stuck on splashscreen in xcode when building to iPhone 3gs

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, uiwebview, ionic-framework

I am looking for some help with the following error message in Xcode whilst trying to run an ionic / cordova app to my iPhone 3gs for testing.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, @"AppDelegate");
        return retVal;
    }
}
```

Screenshot is here - [xcode error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wz9Iq.png)

The console is reading the following -

> 2016-03-04 15:32:36.657 First Campus LAC[945:907] Apache Cordova native platform version 4.0.1 is starting.
>   2016-03-04 15:32:36.683 First Campus LAC[945:907] Multi-tasking -> Device: YES, App: YES
>   2016-03-04 15:32:36.691 First Campus LAC[945:907] CRITICAL: For Cordova 4.0.0 and above, you will need to upgrade to at least iOS 8.0 or greater. Your current version of iOS is 6.1.6.
>   2016-03-04 15:32:36.826 First Campus LAC[945:907] Using UIWebView
>   2016-03-04 15:32:36.838 First Campus LAC[945:907] -[UIWebView setGapBetweenPages:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1f5b8610
>   2016-03-04 15:32:36.845 First Campus LAC[945:907] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIWebView setGapBetweenPages:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1f5b8610'
>   *** First throw call stack:
>   (0x320652a3 0x39cc197f 0x32068e07 0x32067531 0x31fbef68 0xc34dd 0xc2f0f 0xb3977 0xb3037 0xb3523 0xb1b2d 0x9b11b 0x33e8c595 0x33eccd79 0x33ec8aed 0x33f0a1e9 0xb51ff 0x9aee5 0x33ecdad9 0x33ecd663 0x33ec584b 0x33e6dc39 0x33e6d6cd 0x33e6d11b 0x35b295a3 0x3203a683 0x32039ee9 0x32038cb7 0x31fabebd 0x31fabd49 0x33ec4485 0x33ec1301 0x9addb 0x3a0f8b20)
>   libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
>   (lldb)

I have the following set up -

XCode Version 7.2.1 (7C1002)
Ionic @ 1.7.14
Cordova @ 6.0.0
NPM @ 3.8.0
Bower @ 1.7.7
Git @ 2.5.4
SASS @ 3.4.21

Many thanks,
Neil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK: 3GS cannot be upgraded to iOS 7 and the API `[UIWebView setGapBetweenPages:]` has been introduced in iOS 7.

So you have to test on an other device or use iOS 6 only API.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. If I wanted to use the iOS6 only API - would I need to use an older build of Cordova then? Or is this something that is coming from the innAppBrowser plugin?

Comment: Sorry I never used Cordova, I just do not know how it works.

Comment: You need to downgrade your `cordova ios  platform` to `3.9.2` to support iOS 6. Try `cordova platform update ios@3.9.2`.

Comment: Thank you Xvolks & @Beat, I was able to solve this issue using the command suggested. Took me a while as when I ran 'ionic build ios' it was using the latest version of ios so I ran 'cordova build ios' instead and can now test on 3gs again.